# Filter object if property matches value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, angular6

I have an object that looks like this:

```
const faultGroup = 
[{
  comments:"",
  faults:
   [{
     id:31,
     name: "speaker"
    },
    {
     id:22
     name: "earphones"
    },
    {
     id:25
     name: "keyboard"
    }];
}];
```

And I have an array that contains an array of id

```
idArray = [25,22];
```

Intended result:

```
result = ["earphones", "keyboard"];
```

Current solution:

```
result = [];
faultGroup.map(fg => {
  if (!!fg.faults) {
     fg.faults.forEach(fault => {
         for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
            if (idArray[i] === fault.id) {
                this.result.push(fault.name);
            }
         }
     });
   }
});
```

May I know the most efficient way to go about doing this? (not sure how to use filter and includes method in this case) Currently I'm using a combination of map and double for loops. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can `reduce` over the `faultGroup` array, extracting the `faults` array from each item and iterating over it, pushing to the accumulator if the `id` is included in `idArray`:

```js
const faultGroup = [{
  comments: "",
  faults: [{
      id: 31,
      name: "speaker"
    },
    {
      id: 22,
      name: "earphones"
    },
    {
      id: 25,
      name: "keyboard"
    }
  ]
}];
const idArray = [25,22];
const result = faultGroup.reduce((a, { faults }) => {
  if (faults) faults.forEach(({ id, name }) => {
    if (idArray.includes(id)) a.push(name);
  });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

With possible upcoming [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), you could use a mapping with flattening in a single loop by taking the wanted items.

```js
const
    faultGroup = [{ comments: "", faults: [{ id: 31, name: "speaker" }, { id: 22, name: "earphones" }, { id: 25, name: "keyboard" }] }],
    idArray = [25, 22],
    result = faultGroup.flatMap(({ faults }) => faults
        .filter(({ id }) => idArray.includes(id))
        .map(({ name }) => name)
    );
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as well.

```
let result = [];

faultGroup.forEach(({ faults }) => {
  faults
    .filter(({ id }) => idArray.indexOf(id) > -1)
    .forEach(fault => result.push(fault));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var faultGroup = 
[{
  comments:"",
  faults:
   [{
     id:31,
     name: "speaker"
    },
    {
     id:22,
     name: "earphones"
    },
    {
     id:25,
     name: "keyboard"
    }]
}];
idArray = [25,22];

var res = faultGroup.map( f => f["faults"].filter( a => idArray.indexOf(a.id) > -1 ).map( r => r.name ) );

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to get the result:

```js
const data = [{ comments: "", faults: [{ id: 31, name: "speaker" }, { id: 22, name: "earphones" }, { id: 25, name: "keyboard" } ] }]
const ids = [25,22];

const result = data.reduce((r,{faults}) => 
  [...r, ...faults.filter(({id}) => ids.includes(id)).map(x => x.name)], [])

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to start with the reduce since you are going to change the final result form and you would need an accumulator. Then inside just filter the main array based if the ids include its elements and spread the results inside the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` can be used to check all key value pairs :

```js
var result = [], idArray = [25,22], faultGroup = [{ comments:"", faults: [
{ id:31, name: "speaker" }, { id:22, name: "earphones" }, { id:25, name: "keyboard" }] }];

JSON.stringify(faultGroup, (k, v) => idArray.includes(v.id) ? result.push(v.name) : v);

console.log( result );
```